# Screen freezes for about a second every 10-30 seconds

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, freeze

My display keeps freezing for about 1-3 seconds every 10-30 seconds.  I notice in the system monitor that gnome-shell tends to accumulate ram. When it gets to using more than a couple gigs I restart it with Alt-f2 -> r which resets it memory usage to <200mb.  This seems to help for a little while but the problem doesn't go away completely.

I'm thinking it's a display issue because any time there is an animation or video playing, after each freeze it jumps ahead to where it should be had it played continuously.  When the freeze happens while I'm typing, I continue typing like normal and when it finishes the freeze everything typed during the blackout suddenly appears like it should, no missing characters.

This problem started after using Shotcut to edit a video.  I did something that locked it up completely.  The hard drive light went 100% and stayed that way.  I figured I maxed out my ram (16gb) and it was swapping so I gave it a while to work through what it was doing.  After about 10 minutes it never stopped so I hard reset.  Apparently that did not go down gracefully as I've had this glitch ever since.  I've tried reinstalling gnome-shell but that didn't help.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot what is going on.  Could someone help please?

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            14G        5.2G        3.9G        401M        5.5G        8.7G
Swap:           33G          0B         33G

grep -i swap /etc/fstab
# removed swapfile to use ssd instead (2/26/19)
#/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap space on ssd
/dev/disk/by-uuid/07c6e4a1-3379-454f-a727-e3fa386444da none swap sw 0 0

sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 sauldog sauldog 4096 Feb  2 00:53 .
drwx------ 3 sauldog sauldog 4096 Feb 22 19:05 ..
drwxrwxr-x 6 sauldog sauldog 4096 Feb  2 00:53 arc-menu@linxgem33.com


ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Mar 10  2020 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 24  2018 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan 30  2019 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2019 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema done.

Comment: 33G swap is kinda nuts. Are you using a partition on the SSD for swap? Why did you switch from a /swapfile to swap on SSD? What is your disk configuration? If you `sudo swapoff -a` does the problem go away?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, there is a separate swap partition on the SSD.  Switched from swapfile on my spinning drive because the SSD is much faster.  It was new and empty when I added it and since I had a lot of space I gave swap plenty of it.  Nothing changes after running `sudo swapoff -a`

Comment: You can reduce your swap to 4G, and you can use a /path_to/swapfile on the SSD.

Comment: @heynnema I can, yes, but what benefits would I gain from doing so?  Is there anything 'wrong' with the way I have it set up?  Is there any reason it would work perfectly fine for two years before causing problems now?  I feel like this is more of a graphical issue than swap.  I can remove swap altogether and it still persists.

Comment: The stats I posted yesterday were after a fresh reboot.  Now that my desktop has been running for 24 hours the memory consumed by gnome-shell has climbed to 1.5GB (from 200MB) and it's in the top position for cpu-time.  The glitch is also noticeably worse. The cpu usage by gnome-shell spikes during these glitches while there is zero hard drive activity.

I mentioned reinstalling gnome-shell as an attempt to fix this but it didn't help.  Is there a deeper, more thorough way to reinstall?  Or maybe other related packages?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Make sure to start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them :-)

Comment: @heynnema done.

Comment: Please see my answer. Leave the swap, as is, if you wish... but do the gnome-shell extensions part. Report back.

Comment: If my answer solves the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**swap**

16G RAM with a 33G swap is kind of nuts.

I understand moving swap to a partition on SSD, but we should switch back to a 4G /swapfile on the SSD.

I'm also a little concerned about the SSD mounting early enough in the boot process to actually use the swap. Check with `free -h` or `swapon -s`.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

**Note**: Change **/swapfile**, below, to the proper location that you want on the SSD. ie: /path_to/swapfile

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Note**: You can now delete the swap partition on SSD, and add that unallocated space back to some other partition.

**gnome-shell**

There's a known memory leak bug in gnome-shell that causes it to consume lots of memory as time goes on.

The short term fix is to restart gnome-shell with...

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

**gnome-shell extensions**

Too many bad gnome-shell extensions that are probably causing your problem.

My particular pet peeve is that the ones installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions are system-wide for all users, and should actually have been placed in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions so that they'll be local to the current user.

So do this to remove these extensions...

`sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*gcampax.github.com`

Then restart gnome-shell...

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

**Update #1:**

We found that ~/.config/AppImageLauncher config file was being updated frequently. Uninstalled AppImageLauncher and the problem is fixed!

Comment: Arc-menu is the only one I installed, those other system-wide extensions came default.  I looked on extensions.gnome.org and they were all turned off.  But I went ahead and removed them per your instructions.  I went ahead and removed arc-menu too, just to be sure.  I restarted gnome-shell, but nothing has changed.  The problem persists.

Comment: You mentioned the gnome-shell memory leak.  That seems to have gotten much worse lately, gnome-shell grew to over 5.6 GB in 48 hours.  The larger gnome-shell grows, the worse my problem gets.

Comment: @CleoSauldog When the gnome-shell memory usage is high, what percentage of CPU does it take? With no mouse movements, it should average under 3%. You may have installed some other software to cause this severe a problem. Do you dual-boot? Are the OS(s) installed on the hard disk, and your /home on the SSD? How large is your HDD and SSD? Do you have good backups?

Comment: It starts at a normal range below 3% after restarting gnome-shell but climbs to between 3-10% after a day or so, spiking every time the glitch happens.  I do have a dual boot but I just realized when I log into another account on this same installation the glitch goes away.  The home directory is on the same spinning drive and it has been backed up recently.  Looking in the home directory and sorting by last modified, /.config/dconf is the only thing that keeps getting modified staying up to date.  We've definitely narrowed it down but I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: There are a few hidden folders that commonly cause problems. .cache, .local, .config. ONE AT A TIME, change the name of the folder **example: .cache to .cache.HOLD**. Log out, log in, retest. If it doesn't fix the problem, move the newly created .cache folder to the trash, rename the .HOLD folder, immediately log out, log in, and repeat with the next folder.

Comment: I found it! The AppImageLauncher daemon was causing the problem.  I followed your instructions and determined it to be in .config.  I dug around and saw the AppImageLauncher config file was being updated frequently. Changed the daemon setting from true to false and it was fixed!  I went ahead and completely removed the AppImageLauncher with apt. Not necessary.  Thank you, thank you, so very much!!  You were most helpful, you knew the exact right questions to ask and exactly where to look to help me track this down.  That glitch was driving me bonkers.  Thank you again!  Problem solved.

Comment: @CleoSauldog Great news! Thanks for the update, and your help in narrowing down the culprit.